# Rails 4 - Link_to action create with params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

I would like to add a link into my rails app which will allow my users to "like" a resource (property) directly. To click on that link will add the like into the db without asking anything to the user.

The `like` table: `user_id`, `property_id`

As you can see, `user_id` and `property_id` have to be in the `link_to` as params.

**routes.rb:**

```
  resources :likes
  resources :properties
```

**index:**

```
<%= link_to "Like this property", new_like_path(current_user, property.id) %> #does not work but you get the idea
```

**controller:**

```
 def new
    @like = Like.new
  end
def create
    @like = Like.new(like_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @like.save
        format.html { redirect_to @like, notice: 'Like was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @like }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @like.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

So I am in `properties#index` and I would like to call a `create` method to add a like on that property.

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: It just does not work. I don't know how to do that kind of link.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

index:-

```
<%= link_to "Like this property", likes_path(:user_id => current_user.id, :property_id => property.id), :method => :post %>
```

In controller:-

```
def create
@like = Like.new(:user_id => params[:user_id], :property_id => params[:property_id])

respond_to do |format|
  if @like.save
    format.html { redirect_to properties_path, notice: 'Like was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @like }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'new' }
    format.json { render json: @like.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

Comment: I tried but :
 # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def like_params
      params.require(:like).permit(:user_id, :property_id)
    end   It's like the params are not there

Comment: yes i have changed. see the link_to in index  and Like.new in controller